# How this kind of pagination works?

Tags: html, url-rewriting, pagination

This will sound like a silly question, but I searched around for a while until I lost my patience:

How this kind of pagination works?

```
"www.example.com/p/1"
```

How do I do one like that?
What languages should I use?

*NOTE: I am NOT talking about this kind of pagination: "www.example.com?page=1" using variables

Thanks in advance

Comment: please have a look at tutorial of  htaccess file. Using conditional rules, you can redirect  `www.example.com/p/1` to `www.example.com?page=1`

Comment: This assuming the web server is Apache. But you can do something like `RewriteRule ^/p/([0-9]+)$ index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]`. You can use whatever programming language you like as the server will handle translating the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on the language/framework you are using.
It's based on the routing engine used by the framework.

You can also do url re-writing with htaccess files or some libraries (depending your web server).

Without more details there are not many specifics I can give you.

For example for references on ASP.NET MVC routing see this: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx

For references on Rails routing see this: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 2):

As Pradeep said, usually `www.example.com/p/1/` is just a mask over something like `www.example.com?p=1` which the web server translates before trying to do anything else with.

This can be achieved on IIS using something like [global.asax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1xaas8a2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) or on Apache using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)